# Filter associations in ActiveModelSerializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I'm having troubles with associations, ActiveModelSerializers and n+1 queries.

## Some context first

I have a *Match* model which has many *PredictionResult*

There is one *PredictionResult* per match per user and my API should only return *those of the current user*

Same for the *Prediction*, except that it has a model named *Opponent* between him and *Match*. One match can only have 2 predictions per user.

So my output Match should look like:

```
{
  ...basic attributes,
  "prediction_results": [ predictions results of the match and the user ],
  "predictions": [ predictions of the match and the user ]
}
```

## The code

I used to have the following serializer:
    class MatchSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :blabla

```
  belongs_to :winner

  has_many :opponents

  has_many :predictions
  has_one :prediction_result

  def predictions
    object.predictions.where(user: instance_options[:user])
  end

  def prediction_result
    object.prediction_results.where(user: instance_options[:user]).first
  end
end
```

It was working well, but lots of n+1 queries, so I updated my controller to only have

```
  has_many :predictions
  has_many :prediction_results
```

Without the 2 methods in the serializer.

My controller looks like this:

```
@matches = Match.all
@matches = @matches.left_outer_joins(:winner)
@matches = @matches.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN opponents ON opponents.match_id = matches.id")
@matches = @matches.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN players ON players.id = opponents.opponent_id AND opponents.opponent_type = 'Player'")
@matches = @matches.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN teams ON teams.id = opponents.opponent_id AND opponents.opponent_type = 'Team'")
@matches = @matches.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN predictions ON predictions.opponent_id = opponents.id AND predictions.user_id = #{current_user&.id}")
@matches = @matches.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN prediction_results ON prediction_results.match_id = matches.id AND prediction_results.user_id = #{current_user&.id}")
@matches = @matches.includes(:winner, :predictions, :prediction_results, opponents: :opponent)
@matches = @matches.where('predictions.user_id IS NULL OR predictions.user_id = ?', current_user&.id)
@matches = @matches.where('prediction_results.user_id IS NULL OR prediction_results.user_id = ?', current_user&.id)

render json: @matches.distinct, include: '*.*', user: current_user
```

When I run all this in SQL, I get the result I want, predictions and prediction results are filtered, but somehow, my JSON always outputs all the predictions and prediction results of the match (so without the filter)
I don't know where I f*cked up here, and I certainly need a hand on this. Thanks !

Comment: Can you create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?